# Require order in a ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that requires 3 gems to work. My script starts as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'httparty'
require 'imgkit'
require 'twitter'
```

Now, interestingly, the above code works, but only if I require `httparty` first or second. If I require it as the third dependency, I get the following:

`'require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)`

I'd love to learn why this is happening, so I can better understand how ruby handles gem dependencies. Many thanks!

Edit: I am using bundler. This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'

gem 'wkhtmltoimage-binary'
gem 'imgkit'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'httparty'
```

Comment: maybe one of these other gems depends on httparty but does not require it for some reason?

Comment: I don't think this is the case: Obviously, something is *requiring* it, but can not load it. This would suggest, that either `twitter` is fiddling with the gem path, or the gem path contains relative pathes and the twitter gem changes the working directory. @JanKlimo: Could you try to rule out these possibilities, by checking the gem path and the working directory before requiring `httparty`?

Comment: You might want to try using [Bundler](http://bundler.io) and formally declaring your dependencies in a `Gemfile`. `require 'bundler/setup'` can take care of a lot of loading issues for you automatically.

Comment: What are the gem versions? `twitter` switched from HTTParty to Faraday almost 6 years ago: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/commit/80aff88dae11d64673fe4e025cc8f065a6796345

Comment: Also:  Are you sure `/usr/bin/env ruby` is pointing to the Ruby version you're expecting? I just tried to replicate your problem, but for me any order of gems works.

Answer (score 0):

Following tadman's advice, adding `require 'bundler/setup'` solved the problem. More [in the docs](http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html). Thanks!